# Why does my function print out multiples?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def sent_dictionary(text):
    token_dictionary = {}
    both_keys = in_both.keys()

    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    tokens = word_tokenize(str(sentences))

    for token in tokens:
        if token in both_keys:
            token_dictionary[token]=in_both[token]
        print(token_dictionary)
```

I have a dictionary called in_both that contains words that are in the dictionary and my text that looks like this:

```
{'think': -0.125, 'seem': 0.0, 'able': 0.25, 'make': 0.0, 'correct': 0.0, 'understand': 0.125, 'words': -0.125, 'appropriate': 0.0, 'confuse': -0.375, 'underactive': -0.625, ... }
```

[Full dictionary here](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it)

I want my function to take the text input, split into sentences, then into words. Then if the word is also in the in_both dictionary, put it into token_dictionary along with the value that's in in_both.

When I try to use the function, this is what happens:

```
sent_dictionary("His father was a successful local businessman and his mother was the daughter of a landowner. Shakespeare is widely regarded as the greatest writer in the English language and the world's pre-eminent dramatist. He is often called England's national poet and nicknamed the Bard of Avon")
```

The output is:

```
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
```

I want the output to look like:

```
{'language': 0.0, 'often': 0.25}
```

Now that I think about it, there are multiples in my text that I am working with. So I don't want to exclude those, I need all tokens to be accounted for.

Comment: You call print in the outer loop of your nested for loop, you probably want to call it *after* the for loop is complete.

Comment: The problem is that you have a `print(token_dictionary)` inside the `for` loop. So you're printing the whole dictionary over and over again. Just dedent that line so it only happens after the loop is done.

Comment: What do you mean by "all tokens [being] accounted for"?

Comment: If you want to handle duplicate keys by summing up all the values for each key, you should use a `defaultdict(float)` or a `Counter` (both in the `collections` module in the stdlib) instead of a plain dict for `token_dictionary`, then do `token_dictionary[token] += in_both[token]`.

Comment: If you want to handle duplicate keys by, e.g., keeping a set of all values, the idea is the same; just use  `defaultdict(set)`, and `token_dictionary[token].add(in_both[token])`. Or, if you prefer, use a plain dict and do `token_dictionary.setdefault(token, set()).add(in_both[token])`. (The difference is that when you're looking things up later, `defaultdict` will give you an empty set for unknown keys, but a regular dict that you built with `setdefault` will give you `KeyError`s.)

Comment: @abarnert i get a key error.     ---> 12             token_dictionary[token].add(in_both[token])
     13             new_token_dict = token_dictionary
     14             text_values = list(new_token_dict.values())

KeyError: 'who'

Comment: @Shelina You get a `KeyError` having done which solution? Did you replace `token_dictionary` with a `default_dict(set)` instead of a plain `set`?

Comment: @abarnert yes, i replaced token_dictionary with a default_dict(set)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us your updated code, and the complete exception and traceback?